# Best practice for culture resource management in web information systems

Tags: database, sorting, jqgrid, resource-management

I have a general question on resource management. Let's say that i want to support all the languages in the world and I have the resource files for that purpose. Some of the values in the resource files replace for display string data that originates in some DB (MySQL, SQL server, PostgreSQL, whatever).

Now, say you a jqGrid table with sorting on a column that its values come from a DB and replaced by resource file for a specific culture.

Of course, in that culture, sorting might (and quite possibly) have different results than English (as the primary language).

What is the best practice to manage resources that might modify the values of dynamically loaded data, in a way that it doesn't change the DB routines?

(for example, I do not wish to replace dynamically the string from the resource and then perform sorting on the results - it might be time consuming and too costly to handle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I assume is that you have a column containing resource keys in the DB, and want to sort the result by the values for those keys in a specific language?

There is no good answer to that, I'm afraid. If your result set is small (in the hundreds, at most), sorting the result after replacement will be your best bet.

Other than that, I can see no way to do this that doesn't "change the DB routines". You will either have to pass the values into the query and do the substitution in SQL (if the number of keys is small), or hold the resource data in a DB table, JOIN on that table and sort the result.

Comment: Yep - I was afraid of that :-)